# How to group Northwind orders based on Customer ContactName

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller, northwind

I am new to C# and LINQ and I am using Northwind database. My view displays all orders from the database without ordering. I want to display orders based on contact name (customer) and alphabetically: for example, AVARIA and under it all orders of this customer. And so on...

I want something like this:

```
AVARIA

ORDER 1 OF AVARIA FROM DATABASE WITH ITS DETAILS 
ORDER 2 OF AVARIA FROM DATABASE WITH ITS DETAILS  
ORDER 3 OF AVARIA FROM DATABASE WITH ITS DETAILS  

BECUA

ORDER 1 OF BECUA FROM DATABASE WITH ITS DETAILS
ORDER 2 OF BECUA FROM DATABASE WITH ITS DETAILS  

and so on...
```

Because this is showing me all the orders coming from the database without any ordering, like customer X in the first row with an order, then customer Y, then again customer X with another order, and so on. I tried this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Employee).Include(o => o.Shipper);
    var list = orders.OrderBy(x => x.Customer.ContactName);

    return View(list.ToList());
}
```

But it raised the following exception:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

The view works fine.

Please help.

Comment: You don't tell how convert your orders list into a customers list. You should apply the sorting there.

Comment: @GertArnold i tried this :

var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Employee).Include(o => o.Shipper);
            var list = orders.OrderBy(x => x.Customer.ContactName);

            return View(list.ToList());

but im sure the query is not okay because i got exceptions .

Comment: So edit your question and **show** what you tried and also **which** exception you got.

Comment: You're not making this easy. Always show inner exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use group by and orderby. sample:

```
class Program
{

    class grpitem
    {
        public string groupCode;
        public string item;
    }

    static List<grpitem> list = new List<grpitem>()
    {
         new grpitem() {groupCode="3", item="b"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="1", item="b"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="3", item="c"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="2", item="b"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="2", item="a"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="2", item="c"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="1", item="a"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="3", item="a"},
         new grpitem() {groupCode="3", item="d"}
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<grpitem> ordered = list.GroupBy(grp => grp.groupCode)
            .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(grp => grp.item)).OrderBy(g => g.groupCode);

        foreach(grpitem g in ordered)
            Console.WriteLine("groupCode:{0} item:{1}",g.groupCode,g.item);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
groupCode:1 item:a
groupCode:1 item:b
groupCode:1 item:c
groupCode:1 item:d
groupCode:2 item:a
groupCode:2 item:b
groupCode:3 item:a
groupCode:3 item:b
groupCode:3 item:c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GroupBy(...)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var orders = db.Orders.Include(o => o.Customer).Include(o => o.Employee).Include(o => o.Shipper);
    var groupedOrders = orders.GroupBy(o => Customer.Name, o => o);
    // grouped orders is IEnumerable<string, IEnumerable<Order>>
    return View(groupedOrders);
}
```

Comment: o => Customer.ContactName, when i try to access this it says an object reference is required to access non-static field Customer.ContactName

Comment: Does the above code work, but you can't read from o.ContactName? Can you read other properties from the class and where are you reading this property?

Comment: No it doesnt work , when i try to access  Customer.ContactName, it says an object reference is required to access non-static field Customer.ContactName :
var groupedOrders = orders.GroupBy(o => Customer.ContactName , o => o);

There are two different classes Order and Customer in my model

Comment: You have to show more of your classes to get better help.You mention that you have 2 classes in the model but you include 3 classes when you select orders. I am missing something in your code and need to see the problem to be able to solve it.